# Getting count of rows in postgres inheritance

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, count

I am using postgres inheritance, where each base table has around 200 child tables and each child table has around 5 partition table and the total records is around 20CR. I am trying to fetch the count using basic select(*) query but it takes a long time.

Is there any alternative here to get the count within 60 secs

version 12.8

Comment: Please add pg version.

Comment: I don't know what 20CR is and I'm too lazy to find out, but 200 partitions is quite a few already. What PostgreSQL version do you use? And could you share the query plan using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query?

Comment: Query plan is too long as it shows the plan for each table not able to paste here

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an explain (actual rows), but it might not be exact:

```
explain analyze select count(*) from table;
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=180.86..180.87 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=9.389..9.390 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..173.09 rows=3109 width=0) (actual time=3.070..9.255 rows=3156 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.118 ms
 Execution Time: 9.420 ms
(4 rows)

Time: 9,890 ms

 # select count(*)  from table;
 count 
-------
  3156
(1 row)
```

Time: 0,875 ms